# phpunit no phpstorm

Tags: php, testes, testes-de-unidade, phpunit

Irei fazer testes unitários pelo `phpunit` no meu estágio e não consigo colocar ele no projeto. adicionei o arquivo `composer.json` e quando vou tentar adicionar a dependência `phpunit/phpunit`, ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
composer require phpunit/phpunit:8.0.4 -n --no-progress --no-interaction
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 8.0.4 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[8.0.4].
- phpunit/phpunit 8.0.4 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: Essa resposta pode te ajudar: [Como configrar o phpunit da forma certa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/423653/como-configurar-o-phpunit-com-scrutinizer/423792#423792)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao ver o seu código, vejo que na sua máquina não possui a extensão mbstring.

> `phpunit/phpunit 8.0.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.`

Você deve instalar essa extensão (ou ativar ela) antes de tentar instalar o PHPUnit.

**Solução 1 - Ativando a extensão:**

Procure o arquivo de configuração php.ini da sua máquina. Para achar aonde ele se encontra, digite o comando no terminal `php -i`.

Procure nas primeiras linhas uma linha iniciada assim: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path`. O que vier depois indica a pasta aonde está o seu arquivo de configuração.

Localize essa pasta e abra o arquivo `php.ini`. Depois, adicione a seguinte linha:

(Se estiver no Windows)

`extension=php_mbstring.dll`

(Se estiver no Linux)

`extension=php_mbstring.so`

Execute o comando de instalação novamente. Se estiver dando erro, vamos para a 2ª solução:

**Solução 2 - Ativando o mbstring**

No Ubuntu você deve executar o seguinte comando:

`sudo apt install php-mbstring`

Creio que com isso, deve resolver o seu problema.

Espero ter ajudado.

P.S.: Por favor, informe o seu sistema operacional e qual servidor você está utilizando, editando a pergunta, para que possamos oferecer a melhor resposta para você.

**Edição #1, para refletir as alterações na pergunta**

O erro: `Problem 1 - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 8.0.4 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[8.0.4]. - phpunit/phpunit 8.0.4 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.` indica que a versão do PHP não é suportada pela versão mais recente do PHPUnit.

Você pode resolver de duas formas:

- Instalando uma versão antiga do PHPUnit ou,
- Instalando uma versão mais recente do PHP.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: executei o comando para instalar o php-mbstring. Com isso, surgiu um novo erro. editei minha pergunta com esse novo erro. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Caro. O erro `Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 8.0.4 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[8.0.4]. - phpunit/phpunit 8.0.4 requires php ^7.2` diz que o PHPUnit só funciona com versões do PHP acima de 7.2. Você tem que atualizar a versão do PHP.

Se estiver usando Windows, é só procurar um servidor que tenha suporte a PHP 7.3. Se estiver usando o Linux procure no seu gerenciador de pacotes. Se não conseguir achar, atualize o seu sistema Linux.

Comment: Uma dica. Procure manter o que você escreveu antes. Coloque o novo erro abaixo do que você escreveu na sua pergunta, indicando que é uma edição. Assim, mantemos a sequência da conversa.

Comment: Entendi. Irei tentar instalar uma versão mais antiga do phpunit. Obrigado novamente!

Comment: Ok. Se a resposta levar a solução do problema, procure marcar ela como a resposta aceita, clicando no tique verde. Assim, outras pessoas saberão achar a correta. Eu que agradeço.