# Como configurar o phpunit com Scrutinizer?

Tags: php-7, phpunit

Seguindo a documento do [Scrutinizer](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/build/code_coverage) realizei a criação do arquivo `.scrutinizer.yml` no projeto em **PHP**. Analisando outros sites cheguei ao resultado final do arquivo demonstrado abaixo:

```
build:
  environment:
    php:
      version: 7.2
  nodes:
    coverage:
      tests:
        before:
          - "cp .env.example .env"
          - "echo 'END_POINT =your_webhook' > .env"
        override:
          - command: 'php ./vendor/bin/phpunit'
            coverage:
              file: 'phpunit.xml'
              format: 'php-clover'

filter:
  paths:
    - 'src/*'
  excluded_paths:
    - 'vendor/*'
    - 'tests/*'
```

Esta é minha primeira experiência com o *Scrutinizer*. Isso significa que o resultado final deste arquivo está mais para tentativa e erro do uma ação consciente para cada linha de configuração colocada arquivo.

Como podem ver realizei algumas especificações no arquivo, como:

1. Indicar a versão do php usada no projeto.
2. A necessidade de existir um arquivo .env e criação de uma variável local porque utilizo nos testes
3. O comando para rodar o teste `php ./vendor/bin/phpunit`
4. O arquivo de configuração do phpunit `phpunit.xml` - Não sei porque ter isso na verdade.
5. E o formato do teste `php-clover`. Não sei pra que serve isso.

No decorrer da execução do Scrutinizer é rodado todos os testes com sucesso, mas a opção [image: covarage aparece not enable].

O que está faltando fazer para funcionar?
Obs.: Coloquei todas as informações que considerei úteis, mas se precisar de mais detalhes vou adicionando conforme pedirem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos lá, iremos utilizar como ponto de partida que sua máquina tenha a versão `php7.2` com o `xdebug` instalado e configurado. Ao digitar o comando `php -v` a saída no terminal será semelhante a esta:

```
PHP 7.2.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2019 18:23:23) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.11, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.8.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

Antes ainda de fazer o *Scrutinizer* funcionar. Será preciso fazer os testes funcionarem, então:

1. Instale o `phpunit` via `composer`. Veja a [versão do phpunit](https://phpunit.de/supported-versions.html) a ser utilizado de acordo com a versão dos seu php.

```
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "8.0.*",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*"
  },
```

2. [Configure](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/pt_BR/latest/configuration.html) seu arquivo `phpunit.xml`.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <phpunit
            backupGlobals="false"
            backupStaticAttributes="false"
            bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
            colors="true"
            convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
            convertNoticesToExceptions="false"
            convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
            processIsolation="false"
            stopOnFailure="false"
    >
        <testsuites>
            <testsuite name="Package Test Suite">
                <directory suffix=".php">tests</directory>
            </testsuite>
        </testsuites>
    </phpunit>
```

3. Tenha seu arquivo bootstrap configurado sua pasta de teste na raiz do projeto, por ex: `test/bootstrap.php`. Caso não tenha muitas configurações a serem feitas ou nenhuma um simples arquivo como demonstrado abaixo será o suficiente

```
 <?php
  if (!defined('ROOT_DIR')) {
      define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
  }
  require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

4. Crie e rode seus testes unitários. **Nenhum dos passos descritos aqui é mais importante do este** rsrsrs

Para analisar a cobertura de código algumas configurações ainda são necessárias.

1. Em seu arquivo `phpunit.xml` adicione as configurações *[whitelist e logging](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/pt_BR/latest/configuration.html#lista-branca-de-arquivos-para-cobertura-de-codigo)*.

```
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">src/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="target/coverage.html" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70" />
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="target/coverage.xml"/>
        <log type="coverage-text" target="target/coverage.txt"/>
    </logging>
```

2. Crie na raiz do projeto a pasta `target/`. Essa pasta servirá para armazenar os arquivos configurados em *logging* no arquivo `phpunit.xml` gerados na cobertura de código. **Não esqueça de adicionar essa pasta no arquivo `.gitignore`**. Não precisa *commitar* ela.
3. Para facilitar sua vida. Crie os scripts no arquivo `composer.json` para não precisar lembrar do comando toda hora. No caso, temos dois scripts. Um para rodar os testes normais e o outro para rodar os teste de *coverage*.

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "php ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --bootstrap ./tests/bootstrap.php --configuration ./phpunit.xml",
    "test-coverage": "php ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --bootstrap ./tests/bootstrap.php --configuration ./phpunit.xml --coverage-clover ./target/coverage.xml",
  }
```

Agora sim chegamos onde queremos. Para configurar o *Scrutinizer*:

- Faça o login com *git* ou *bitbucket*
- Crie o arquivo `.scrutinizer.yml` na raiz do seu projeto e adicione as configurações necessárias. Links que te ajudaram: [melhores práticas](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/configuration/best_practices), [estrutura geral do arquivo .yml](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/configuration), [cobertura de código](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/build/code_coverage). Seguem um arquivo de exemplo:

```
  build:
    environment:
      php:
        version: 7.2
    nodes:
      coverage:
        tests:
          override:
            - command: 'php ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --bootstrap ./tests/bootstrap.php --configuration ./phpunit.xml'
              coverage:
                file: './target/coverage.xml'
                format: 'clover'

  filter:
    paths:
      - 'src/*'
    excluded_paths:
      - 'vendor/*'
      - 'tests/*'
```

No arquivo `.scrutinizer.yml` repasso algumas configurações, como:

- A versão do php que os testes devem rodar
- O comando a ser rodado
- O arquivo `./target/coverage.xml` que o *Scrutinizer* irá utilizar ler as informações de cobertura de código
- O formato do teste utilizado `clover`
- As pasta que o *coverage* rodou `src/*`
- E as pastas que o *Scrutinizer* não deve levar em consideração referente ao *coverage* `vendor/*` e `tests/*`

Segue também um [projeto de exemplo](https://github.com/djalmamanfrin/slack-sdk) para ver na prática.